# 301 Rewrite redirecting to wrong place

Tags: http-status-code-301

I am taking over a site and I'm trying desperately to get our affiliate sites to stay at their rewrite paths. Instead, they all forward to the home page. I want 404s obviously to redirect and I know I am missing something here, but I've tried everything I can think of and I obviously need another pair of brains here. This is how it was written and I'm not sure how to edit it for what I need. How do I stop the affiliate pages from then forwarding to the index?? Seems like every edit I made breaks things!

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteRule ^aff/(.*)$ /index.php/aff/?aff=$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [R=301,NC]


ErrorDocument 404 /redirect/404_redirect.php
Redirect 301 /redirect/404_redirect.php http://privatemoneyexchange.org
```